# How to handle rendering json errors from network requests made by gems in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Stripe to handle subscription payments. I have a `PaymentsController` that handles when a user enters their credit card info. Stripe creates a user and attaches a subscription to that user. The Stripe gem handles these network requests. However, I'd like to render a json error if Stripe hits an error at any point during it's request to either create the user or attach a subscription. Is there a way to handle errors from network requests by gems?

**payments_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
     Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY_TEST']

    // render an error if there is an issue creating a customer
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
      email: current_user.email,
      source: request.params[:id]
    })

    stripe_plan = ENV['STRIPE_PLAN_ID_TEST']

    // render an error if there is an issue creating a subscription
    subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create({
      customer: customer.id,
      items: [{ plan: stripe_plan }],
    })

    current_user.subscription_plan = 1
    current_user.save

    if current_user.save
      render json: { 'success': true }, status: 200
    else
      render json: { 'error': 'Some error with saving user here' }, status: 500
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you will need to handle that manually based on the type of error that is thrown here in the docs

https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#error_handling

The way you could handle that inline on any stripe error is to wrap your call in a begin block and return a render json: in the rescue portion.

```
// render an error if there is an issue creating a customer
begin
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
    email: current_user.email,
    source: request.params[:id]
  })
rescue ::Stripe::StripeError => e
  render json: { 'error': 'some error'}
  return 
end
```

More generically, you could wrap that logic in a proc and then call that so that you exit the context when returning.

Comment: Great, thank you. I wasn't sure if this was API specific or could be handled more generically, so appreciate the thorough response.